# How to create a light oval-shaped CSS3 shadow

Tags: css

I know how to use CSS3 shadows. However I am trying to achieve a specific design. I want the shadow to be a lot lighter and faded off on the left and right edges, please see image attached.

[image: Shadow Design]

The only code I have come up with is the following. But not sure how to make the edges fade out more.

```
 .shadow {box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #000000;}
```

Any tips be helpful

Comment: Have you tried using css gradients? I think that's the only way to achieve this via CSS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use a combination of box-shadow, border-radius and clip.

http://dabblet.com/gist/2225507

Comment: This is perfect! Didn't think of using Pseudo-class :before or border-radius to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
[image]

> box-shadow: 0px 20px 37px -28px #000000;

note about parameters:
[CSS3's Box-Shadow Adds Drop Shadows, Inner Shadows](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2123-CSS3-s-Box-Shadow-Adds-Drop-Shadows-Inner-Shadows)

Comment: Slightly but not quite there. But @martinjlowm solution is perfect

Answer (score 1):

hi you can create oval shaped css3 shadow through border-radius & box-shadow....

or can see the live demo:-http://jsbin.com/elacen/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

you can play around with box-shadow and gradients here

[css3 gen](http://css3generator.com/)

but i don't think you can apply fading on the shadow